# Linux command to move all the files from var/A to var/

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, path, mv

I guess that this question has been asked here, but I didn't find it.

I am at directory var/ and I have a folder var/A that have some files inside, what I want is to move this files inside A to var/. so what i want to do is the following:

from:

```
var
├── A
|   ├── file1.txt
|   └── file2.txt
└── file3.txt
```

to:

```
var
├── file1.txt
├── file2.txt
└── file3.txt
```

In /var I have tryed the following commands

`sudo mv A /`

`sudo mv A/ ./`

`sudo mv A/ .`

And no one had worked. Thank you in advance

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to replicate your situation.

```
.
└── var
    ├── A
    │   ├── file1.txt
    │   └── file2.txt
    └── file3.txt

2 directories, 3 files
user@host:~/soQ$ mv var/A/*.txt var/ && rm -rf var/A/
user@host:~/soQ$ tree

.
└── var
    ├── file1.txt
    ├── file2.txt
    └── file3.txt
```

Hope this helps!

If you want to do this from `var` just do `mv A/*.txt . && rm -rf A/`

Also, let's assume you have the following structure in your directory.

```
.
├── A
│   ├── file3.txt
│   └── folder1
│       ├── file1.txt
│       └── file2.txt
└── file4.txt
```

If you want to copy just the `*.txt` file in var you need to use find like this:

`find ./A/* -type f -exec mv {} ${PWD} \; && rm A`

This looks at all the files and folders and returns the path for each file (each .txt for example) and then executes `mv` on each line and moves the files into the current directory (`${PWD}`).

Comment: This is a little example, inside A i have more files and folders

Comment: you apply the same logic no matter how many files you have. Also, I assume that all your files are of type `.txt`. if you want to copy everything you can just replace `*.txt` with `*`. I see you say you have folders as well. Let me try something to see if it works as I think it should do you want to copy the folders as well or just take the files in each folder?

Comment: mv works if you have folders as well (it copies the folders). try this if you want to copy just the files. `find ./A/* -type f -exec mv {} ${PWD} \;`

Answer (score -1):

I have found the answer:

`mv A/* .`

I hope it could help another one

Answer (score -1):

You have to specify the right path or match
if you want to move the entire files or directory you have to something
like this using * (wildcards)
`user@akuma:~/var$ mv ./A/* ./`

You can type `mv --help` in your terminal for more information to see more option like below

```
 user@akuma:~/WORKSPACE/Trash$ mv --help

  Usage: mv [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST
  or:  mv [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY
  or:  mv [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...
  Rename SOURCE to DEST, or move SOURCE(s) to DIRECTORY.

  Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.
     --backup[=CONTROL]       make a backup of each existing destination file
 -b                           like --backup but does not accept an argument
 -f, --force                  do not prompt before overwriting
 -i, --interactive            prompt before overwrite
 -n, --no-clobber             do not overwrite an existing file
 If you specify more than one of -i, -f, -n, only the final one takes effect.
  --strip-trailing-slashes  remove any trailing slashes from each SOURCE
                             argument
 -S, --suffix=SUFFIX          override the usual backup suffix
 -t, --target-directory=DIRECTORY  move all SOURCE arguments into DIRECTORY
 -T, --no-target-directory    treat DEST as a normal file
 -u, --update                 move only when the SOURCE file is newer
                             than the destination file or when the
                             destination file is missing
 -v, --verbose                explain what is being done
 -Z, --context                set SELinux security context of destination
                             file to default type
     --help     display this help and exit
     --version  output version information and exit

  The backup suffix is '~', unless set with --suffix or SIMPLE_BACKUP_SUFFIX.
  The version control method may be selected via the --backup option or through
  the VERSION_CONTROL environment variable.  Here are the values:

none, off       never make backups (even if --backup is given)
numbered, t     make numbered backups
existing, nil   numbered if numbered backups exist, simple otherwise
simple, never   always make simple backups

GNU coreutils online help: <http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/>
Full documentation at: <http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/mv>
or available locally via: info '(coreutils) mv invocation'
```